Power BI DAX - Islands and Gaps method into a measure
I am trying to filter a set of data to group them by a metric (for me it's not a timestamp, but a distance).
I would like to define the start/end using a measure. I could pre-filter it when importing the data, but the report is dynamic and the partition by items changed based on the selection of the user.
Here is an overview of my data (a part of it):
"From","To","Category","Electrification","Last inspection","Last work"
14000,14000,,,,
75064,75064,Z,"25kV",2022-08-20,1995-07-01
39208,39208,Z,"25kV",2016-08-09,1997-07-01
25000,25000,Z,"25kV",2015-10-28,1997-07-01
71958,71958,Z,"25kV",2022-08-20,1997-07-01
60360,60360,Z,"25kV",2019-05-11,1997-07-01
30788,30788,Z,"25kV",2017-04-11,1997-07-01
46016,46016,Z,"25kV",2022-10-08,1997-07-01
24079,24079,Z,"25kV",2015-10-30,1997-07-01
40339,40339,Z,"25kV",2016-08-09,1997-07-01
16714,16714,Z,"25kV",2023-01-28,1997-07-01
58602,58602,Z,"25kV",2018-05-23,1997-07-01
27603,27603,Z,"25kV",2017-04-12,1997-07-01
14995,14995,Z,"25kV",2013-06-18,1997-07-01
57100,57100,Z,"25kV",2022-10-01,1997-07-01
26923,26923,Z,"25kV",2017-04-12,1997-07-01
45616,45616,Z,"25kV",2022-10-08,1997-07-01
44389,44389,Z,"25kV",2022-10-09,1997-07-01
37055,37055,Z,"25kV",2016-08-01,1997-07-01
18189,18189,Z,"25kV",2023-01-29,1997-07-01

What I want to achieve is a "summarized" table based on the from and to.
So far, I just did this:
From = calculate min(From))
and
To = calculate max(To))
This does not give the right answer. It mixes the groups, and do not take into account the gaps.
This is what I get:

But the first line should be split into each segment. For example, it should go from 14000 to 14763, and then the second line, and then the third line should be 14815 to 14843 with the empty columns then.
Any hint of how can I achieve what I want ?

Update your question with more details on your data, slicer or use selection etc... Share your data model with a few row samples. Alternatively, share a sample PBIX on a public share (eg OneDrive, Google Drive, Drop Box etc...).

I have tried to add a part of my data, and some explanations of what I got, and what I would like to have. Let me know if that makes it more clear.

Your From and To are identical, is that right? In your visual where are the From and To columns coming from? Ultimately these need to be dynamic. If you could create a sample PBIX and share a link to it (via One Drive, Google Drive, Drop Box etc...) then it would be a great help.

The From To in the visual is the measure that computes the min/max.
